# JSONobject works in intellij but not when run from command line

Tags: java, json, maven, intellij-idea

I have used maven to install JSON support to my Java project in IntelliJ. The project runs without problems while using JSONObject when I run it from the IntelliJ console. When I open the IntelliJ terminal and run from the command line I get the following error.

[image: error about jsonobject from command line]

Comment: Possibly not getting packaged properly? `mvn clean install` then run her.

Comment: most likely those packages are in your IDE environment, but not in your OS environment

Comment: You need to add the dependencies to the class path when executing the program.

Comment: What command are you using in your terminal?

Comment: java com.company.Main

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue where everything ran well when executed from IDE (IntelliJ) but throwing same "NoClassDefFound" error when executing jar file in command line.

Assuming you are using Maven, below is the best workaround I found: [How to Create an Executable JAR with Maven](https://www.baeldung.com/executable-jar-with-maven)

> Henry's answer "*You need to add the dependencies to the class path when executing the program.*" provide the best clue.